# Problems with compiling Beginner Tutorials [Solved]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to ROS and was trying to compile the Beginner Tutorials as explained in ROS tutorial website. I am getting the following error

> +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
> -- Using these message generators:  CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:268
> (message):
> Could not find
> 'share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake'
> (searched in
> '/home/titoro/catkin_ws/devel'). Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:70
> (generate_messages)

I am at my wits end trying to figure out the problem. I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
I somehow messed up CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, I fixed it and now its working. Thanks for the help.

Regards,
TM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202401/problems-with-compiling-beginner-tutorials-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aracanid](https://answers.ros.org/users/20303/aracanid/) on 2015-02-03**:
Do you have std_msgs installed? http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2016-10-09**:
How did you fix your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH? (Ok delete build/devel and source /opt/ros/distro/setup.bash seemed to do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just FYI, you shouldn't be manually adjusting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, you should be letting the `setup.bash` script located in the `devel/` directory of your workspace manage your environment variables for you. Is your problem solved now?

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on 2015-02-04**:
Yeah I realized that later, as I was trying to link OpenCV with ROS I changed CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Yeah my problem is solved.